# Multiple lines per item in an Ms Access listbox using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, activex

I'm trying to populate a MsAccess listbox using VBA, but some fields are too long to appear in only one line and I need to split the info in multiple lines. But... after googled a lot I didn't find how to do it... seems as the listbox don't support multiline. Somebody knows how to do it?

I'm using Access 2010

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish a Word Wrap of sorts for the listbox? To my knowledge, MS Access listboxes don't support this natively.

Answer (score 0):

I used a 2 line wide combo box that shows about 70 characters then used this to allow the first line to fill itself with empty spaces

```
Person: Left([LastName] & ", " & [FirstName] & "                                                                  ",70) & [tblDepartments].[DeptName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use a listbox, but what you can do is use a continues form, and with correct formatting, the continues form (placed on the form as a sub form) will look very much like a list box.

I will state that such a listbox is useful for selection, but would not be of much use for a bound form with a bound listbox.

Here is a screen shot of a listbox and a continues sub form.

[image]

On the right side, that is a continues form as a sub form. Such sub forms DO ALLOW multiple lines and larger text boxes that can continue multiple lines of text. And in above ALSO note how I have a check box (so a listbox would not work for my needs).

So depending on your UI needs you could consider using a continues sub form with text boxes that display more than one line of text. So a continues form can display pictures or larger text boxes. Here is a continues form in access with pictures:

[image]

Note again how the text boxes have more then one line of text.

So with correct formatting, a continues form can/will look much list a listbox as the first screen shot shows. If the UI is only to select/display information, then a continues form is a possible choice. If you need to "save" the selected row as a choice to the underlying table in a form, then above likely not a great choice.